# LWC: NavigationMixin.Navigate for communities url encodes the pageName

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am going through the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) and things seem pretty straight forward:

```
{
    type: 'comm__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        pageName: 'home'
    }
}
```

However I need to set the pageName like so - `pageName : 'case/5005578AVQAA2'`. Or the whole piece of code would look like this:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type : 'comm__namedPage',                                                                     
    attributes : {
        pageName : 'case/5005578AVQAA2',
    },
});
```

What I found out is that when the url gets created that `/` character in the pageName gets urlEncoded and transformed to `%2F`.

So what the browser tries to navigate to is `someCommunityUrl/case%2F5005578AVQAA2`.

How do I prevent the url encoding? Is it happening for security reasons?

**EDIT**

Since documents are not supported I tried the same with `Case` and still get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Added based on comments**

For navigating to any record, you should use `standard__recordPage` (provided, user has access to record). For example, for navigating to case:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin, CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Poc extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    showRecord() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: '500280000068Gv7AAE',
                objectApiName: 'Case',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

According to [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=docs_documents_to_files.htm&type=5),
Documents is not available in lightning experience. Even if you use pageReference `standard__recordPage` or [standard__namedPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_open_files), you cannot access documents in lightning.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

In a community, you cannot even create a page with `/` in its name

[image]

Not sure if you are trying to view `document` but `5005578AVQAA2` is not an Id.

Comment: Sorry I put a random number there. But yes that's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Nonetheless I am getting this result on `case` as well. I know `case` is supported and I can access the url going to `someCommunityUrl/case/{thecaseid}` but I still get the urlencoding of the `/` character after `case`. Sorry for the confusion, I also updated my original question to go with case since my issue is specifically with the encoding and less so with the actual page I am navigating to.

Comment: ok, that is possible, added in answer

Comment: Thanks for that but my requirements are to stay on the community url but navigate to .../case/{thecaseid}

I am not supposed to go to the standard object page for the case.

Comment: You mean as a modal?

Comment: Never mind you were absolutely correct! I just did some testing in the community. It appears that navigating using the `standard__recordPage` type doesn't redirect away from the community, which is what I was afraid of, but instead it loads it within the community layout.